# position <a> link over <img> with responsive behaviour

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In my React application I want to place several links via `<a>` over an image `<img>`.
That is basically not a problem however when you resize the window (e.g. different device) it scales the position of the link and of the image differently.

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tszc7b3q/) to show the behaviour. 
If one rescales the window buttom right, you can see that the link is not "glued" to the image.
How do I achieve this?

I have this functional component (as shown in the fiddle):

```
<div class="parentDiv">

    <div className={styles.imgWrapper}>
        <img 
            className={styles.imgResponsive} 
            src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/08/22/27/flower- 
            3140492__480.jpg" 
        />
        <div class="divLink">
            <a href="some_url">Some link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this css:
With this you can move the link around over the image but it is not glued to the image.

```
.parentDiv {
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.imgResponsive {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.divLink {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
}
```

How do I achieve the desired behaviour?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you use pixels instead of %, it won't move because px doesn't change when browser resizes `.divLink { position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 20px; }`

Comment: @eyl327 thank you but that only works to some extent. If I use fixed pixels like left: 400px it might not be on the screen anymore for small devices

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a *size*  for the image in its CSS rule, either in px or in percent, otherwise the image will be displayed at its original size, which will not be scaled / not repsonsive.

Setting `width` should be sufficient, but to be on the save side, you can add `height: auto`, or vice versa, define `height` and add `width: auto`

For the text link, it would probably better to center it, using `left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`. This will work better regarding responsiveness. You might also define a smaller `font-size` in a media query.

ADDITION (after taking a closer look at the fiddle you provided):

1.) You have a `div` layer in between the `parentDiv` and the image itself: The `.imgWrapper` DIV. You need CSS settings for that: Make it the same size as the parentWrapper by adding this:

```
.imgWrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

That way, the image setting `height: 100%` can relate to the 70vh `height` setting of `.parentDiv`.

2.) In the fiddle, there is no reactJS, so you need to notate the classes in the HTML code as regular HTML attributes there, for example `<img class="imgResponsive" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/08/22/27/flower-3140492__480.jpg" />`

The result: https://jsfiddle.net/9fqohL2m/1/

Comment: thanks for your answer. I added `height: 100%` and `width: auto` and updated the fiddle. But as you can see, it does not solve the issue. The only way to "glue" the link to the image is using `px` so far but that causes issues with different divices

Comment: please note the addition to my answer an the fiddle link I added

Comment: ok that is already pretty close to what I have in mind. In your fiddle if you change the width of the frame it does exactly what I want. If you change the hight of the frame the link still is not "glued" to the image. However I changed inside `.imgResponsive` the `width: 100%` instead of auto and then it workds both ways. But then the picture is distorted. What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - the link (i.e. the text) always is positioned 20% from the top and 10% from the left - at least that's its left top. As I mentioned – I would position the link text as I already wrote previously.

Comment: Yes the link is always x% top and y% left. But when you resize the frame in fiddle of the image the link does not stay on the exact same location of the image. ONLY if you resize the width but not resizing the top. You can achieve this with `.imgResponsive {...width:100%}` but that will ofcourse change proportion of image. I hope I made it clearer now

Comment: ok that is strange. I uploaded screenshots to show the behaviour [pic1](https://ibb.co/nnCQnp6) [pic2](https://ibb.co/kmKnZzV) I hope that works

Comment: Ok, so: The problem is that the image `width` setting is `auto`, which does *not*  supply a valid reference for the `left: 10%;` percentage setting of `.linkDiv`. Instead those 10% relate to the width of `.imgWrapper`, which causes what you describe. But as long as you want to keep the correct proportion of the image and still use images with different proportions, there is no CSS solution. You 'd have to get the rendered image width by javascript and set the `left` parameter of the link based on that (still by js). Or you use images (or image containers) which all have the same proportions.

Comment: Ok that was some important information. I think that is the way to go. So far I am getting the window size dynamically. With `onLoad` I am getting the size of the image but that does not retrigger so I need to figure out how to get this dynamically too. I am not sure what you meant with your last sentence. Even if they all have same proportions and I set `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` they will still be distorted once I just change one of those

Comment: Explaining my last sentence: Your image height is always 70vh, so if all your images have (as an example) a proportion of 3:2 in landscape mode, you could set the width of `.imgWrpapper`  to 46.6666vh (which is 2/3 of 70vh), and the width of the image inside that to 100%. Then the `left: 20%` setting of the link will always be calculated based on those 46.6666vh width of the image, independent of the window width.

Answer (score 1):

Little correction as the default browser style create problems with margins:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-block-start:0;
    margin-block-end:0;
}
.parentDiv {
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.imgResponsive {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.divLink {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20vw;
    left: 20vw;
}
```

the `* {}` applyes the style to all objects with a low priority.
if you still have problems you can take a look on the code i used to place markers on a map [here](https://www.velespiegate.it/isole-tremiti/)
Hope this time it will work

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. It is interesting to see how you did in on your page. Looks nice btw :) I think the differenc is, that you have set your `width:100%` which is why you it works for changing the width. For the hight you have some sort of scroll view so you dont't really change the height of the div (you are not comprimising it - I don't know the right term here). So that might be something to think about myself to put it in a scroll view....thanks for that insight

Answer (score 0):

you need to resize the image with the page or use pixels:
if you want the image to resize with the window:

```
.parentDiv {
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.imgResponsive {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.divLink {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
}
```

else if you want the image to be fixed-width (i think is better to not use that method as it create problems with different device sizes):

```
.parentDiv {
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.imgResponsive {
    position:relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.divLink {
    position: absolute;
    top: 96px;
    left: 96px; /*adjust the values to move the link*/
}
```

hope it will help

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With the fixed pixels works to some extent but like you said this is not the best way to go for different devices. Your first solution however does not work if you put this in the fiddle, both link and image scale/move differently